# Contact Form Not Flagging Errors PHP

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm trying to create a contact form for a website, but it's not handling errors correctly. When an invalid email address is entered or a field is left blank, it is still trying to send the email instead of showing the error message. I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this. If no errors occur, it should send the contact form out and send a confirmation email to the address listed in the form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Leah Stephens</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/contact-styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="hire">
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>

    <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
      <div class="field name-box">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Who Are You?"/>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <?php if(isset($errors['name'])) { echo $errors['name']; } ?>
      </div>

      <div class="field email-box">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@email.com"/>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <?php if(isset($errors['email'])) { echo $errors['email']; } ?> 
      </div>

      <div class="field msg-box">
        <textarea name="message" id="msg" rows="4" placeholder="Your message goes here..."/></textarea>
        <label for="msg">Msg</label>
        <?php if(isset($errors['message'])) { echo $errors['message']; } ?>
      </div>

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc3YCQUAAAAAFHsT-Zh6UbHaYebDKeKx_Ywr8qb
"></div>
      <br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
  </section>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="../js/contact-js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
$myEmail = "example@email.net";
        $errors=[];
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];


            if (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])){
                    $error['name'] = 'Please enter your name';
            }

            if (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                    $error['email'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
            }

            if (!isset($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['message'])){
                    $error['message'] = 'Please enter your message';
            }



            if(empty($errors)){
                $to = $myEmail;
                $subject = "Contact Form Submission: $name";
                $body = "From: $name\n Email: $email\n Message:\n $message";
                $header = "From: $myEmail\n";
                $header .= "Reply-To: $email";

                $confirmSubject = "Contact Form Confirmation";
                $confirmBody = "Hi!\n Thank you for reaching out. I\'ll do my best to get back to you within the next 48 hours. Have a great day!";
                $confirmHeader = "From: $email\n"; 
                $confirmHeader .= "Reply-To: $myEmail";

                mail($to, $subject, $body);
                mail($email, $confirmSubject, $confirmBody);
                header('Location: ../index.html');
            }
        }
```

Comment: `$errors` vs `$error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that you have not initialised the **$error['email']** OR other similar variables before you have used them. You are initialising them later in the next page. You will definitely not get the error message you are intending to display.

A solution could be, instead of linking your form to mail.php , set **action=""** and write the php code for mail.php on the original page itself.

And, checkout for **$error** spelling, you have spelled it **$errors**

Comment: Moving the contents of mail.php to the html page is causing google recaptcha to flag an error as soon as the page is loaded. Is there a specific spot the php code needs to go to prevent this?

Comment: Use it just below the h1 tag you have used, or you can use it anywhere but before the if statements.